# What's the benefit of using the Thread.Sleep method in a backgroundworker?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

Wherever I see examples of using the `BackgroundWorker` in .NET I see people adding `Thread.Sleep(int)`. Maybe I am missing something, but what's its benefit if you don't want to wait? Wherever I use `BackgroundWorker` I am performing lengthy operations which I want them to be completed as soon as possible.

Comment: Maybe they don't want it to complete as soon as possible and want other thread to run. In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t(v=vs.110).aspx), "If the value [...] is zero, the thread relinquishes the remainder of its time slice to any thread of equal priority that is ready to run."

Comment: If it is an *example* it may be a stand in for the actual long running task.

Answer (score 3):

**If you don't want to wait**, there isn't one. People may be using this to share time between other threads as @the_lotus commented.

Also, since you mentioned seeing this **in examples**, you have probably witnessed someone deciding to type one, easy to comprehend line in their tutorial rather than generating enough code that it actually takes long enough to run to demonstrate the background worker.

Answer (score 2):

It is *technically* wrong, BGW has a design flaw and doesn't have the equivalent of TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning.  The kind of option you need to prevent BGW from clogging the thread-pool when its DoWork event handler runs too long.  It will when you call Thread.Sleep() in the DoWork event handler.  But it almost always does anyway, a programmer tend to grab BGW when a UI operation takes more than a second.  It should have used a Thread instead.

Then again, BGW is very simplistic and that's never a flaw when threading is required.  Writing threaded code correctly is just plain hard to get right.  The average usage is one, maybe two, workers in flight at the same time.  And then the design flaw just doesn't matter that much.  BGW otherwise does next to nothing to make it simple to restart a worker, usually a good-enough reason for a programmer to fall back to Sleep().

Blanket advice is to use Task instead, Task.Delay() is unbeatable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular reason for doing this. There is no relationship between BackgroundWorker and Thread.Sleep.

The only reason to sleep is of you want to delay execution (or, very rarely, to induce a context switch).