# Sleep background worker for dynamic time limits

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I'm developing a windows forms application. In my case I have to implement a progress bar with marquee effect for time consuming API call.

```
    private void View_btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        
      this.view.ProgressBarVisible = true;
    
      this.bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
      this.bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
      this.bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
      this.bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bgw_DoWork);
      this.bgw.ProgressChanged +=
          new ProgressChangedEventHandler(Bgw_ProgressChanged);
      this.bgw.RunWorkerCompleted +=
          new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
      this.bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    
    private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        
      // runjob
      connection = new Connection(...);
      response = connection.Runjob(...);
    
      if (response != null) {
        if (response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed &&
            response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created) {
          string jobId = JObject
                             .Parse(response.Content) ["job_id"]
                             .ToString();
          string status = "new";
          int delayTime;
    
          // set initial delay time
          delayTime = count * 2;
    
          // check job status by jobid
          // new|queued|processing|completed|accounted|failed
    
          do {
            Thread.Sleep(delayTime);
            EfResponse = connection.CheckJobStatus(jobId);
            status = JObject
                         .Parse(EfResponse.Content) ["process_state"]
                         .ToString();
            delayTime = 3;
          } while (!(status == "accounted" || status == "failed"));
        }
   }

private void Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.view.ProgressBarVisible = false;
    this.view.Close();
    this.bgw.CancelAsync();
    this.bgw = null;
}
```

Initially I have to set a delay time for before calling `connection.CheckJobStatus(jobId)`, it's a dyanamic value and after 1st job status check then have to delay 3sec for each method call. `Thread.Sleep()` is not doing what I wanted here. Since this `connection.CheckJobStatus(jobId)` method is running with background worker, I need a way to sleep bgw here.

Comment: Do you know Timers? For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: [What's the benefit of using the Thread.Sleep method in a backgroundworker?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31206337/14171304)

Comment: Just use `Task.Delay` and `await`, the `BackgroundWorker` is effectively deprecated